# Zend_Date use Z instead of +00:00 for ISO 8601

Tags: php, date, zend-framework, utc

Zend_Date returns +00:00 instead of Z:

```
$date = $order->getCreatedAtStoreDate();
$date->setTimezone('UTC');
$date->toString(Zend_Date::ISO_8601)
// Returns: 2011-07-21T15:18:36+00:00
```

Wanted: 2011-07-21T15:18:36Z

Anyway I can make Zend_Date to use Z?

I got a workaround with `str_replace('+00:00', 'Z', $date->toString(Zend_Date::ISO_8601))` but I don't like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it's a valid ISO 8601 implementation and none of the other [date constants](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.date.constants.html) will get you what you want, you should probably just use your own formatter string: `$date->toString('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');`

Note that this is only correct behavior when you set the time zone to UTC first, so you may want to wrap them together in a quick helper.